# Weird margin/padding on the side of my site

Tags: html, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation, margin

So im using the foundation frameworks for my wordpress build. I cant seem to figure out why im getting this weird margin or padding on the right side when i drop down to tablet or mobile view.

Anyone ever seen this or know of a fix?

Heres my dev site. if you size the browser down to tablet or phone size and scroll to the left or right it will show up.

I'm using Chrome

```
body {
    background: url(../img/dark-grungewall.jpg) repeat;
    height: auto;
}

.site-container {
    background: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 63px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.83);
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

I wanna say the error is coming from my containing divs or body but im not really sure.

http://dev.solarinnovations.com/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me in the past when using the `.row` class from Bootstrap. Try putting `overflow:hidden` in the style part of the wrapper/container class and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code, you set a max-width. This max-width is stopping the site from stretching across the entire window.

```
.row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 87.5em;
  width: 100%;
}
```

You can fix it by easily using:
`max-width:100%;`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work, thanks for looking though